# Pre-launch report details Google Play Store android.app.RemoteServiceException$CannotDeliverBroadcastException: can't deliver broadcast

Tags: java, android, exception

Exception android.app.RemoteServiceException$CannotDeliverBroadcastException: can't deliver broadcast

```
at android.app.ActivityThread.throwRemoteServiceException (ActivityThread.java:1980)
```

at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mthrowRemoteServiceException

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2242)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:201)``
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:288)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7898)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:936)

Answer (score 0):

If you are still struggling with this, please take a look at this SO thread

[CannotDeliverBroadcastException only on Pixel devices running Android 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72902856/cannotdeliverbroadcastexception-only-on-pixel-devices-running-android-12)

The issue has been confirmed by the AOSP project

[Google Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/245258072)

In my case the crashes were only on Samsung devices running Android 13(with a little bit different line numbers in the stack trace). Might be due to not having the patch released yet. The proposed solution with **Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler** seems to be the only way. It is also the suggested workaround from AOSP team

[Google issue tracker dev confirmation](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/245258072#comment60)

Comment: The solution prevents app from crash or only silence/absorb it in order to prevent reporting to firebase/play console?

Comment: It is to prevent reporting. For my case the app freezes and an ANR dialog will appear as the UncaughtExceptionHandler is assigned to main thread . Not optimal, but it is this or the crash. I will try to just skip report and still restart app. Thanks for reminding me of this problem.