# CannotDeliverBroadcastException On Samsung devices running Android 13 (API 33)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, samsung

We got lot of crash reports from Firebase regarding this crash.

```
Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException$CannotDeliverBroadcastException: can't deliver broadcast
       at android.app.ActivityThread.throwRemoteServiceException(ActivityThread.java:2219)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-$$Nest$mthrowRemoteServiceException()
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2508)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8762)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

Crash happens only on Samsung devices running android 13 (API 33)

We followed this post
[CannotDeliverBroadcastException only on Pixel devices running Android 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72902856/cannotdeliverbroadcastexception-only-on-pixel-devices-running-android-12)

The thing is - we can't just silence/absorb this crash, as some of our app functionality is build on the broadcast (BroadcastReceiver, registered in Manifest).

We need to actually **prevent** this crash (somehow :))

We checked also this one on google issue tracker but it seems there is no solution
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/245258072

Any of you found a solution for this?
Thanks

Comment: What data are you sending? How you are sendBroadcast(Using context or LocalBroadcastManager)?

Comment: @PravinDivraniya We do not send broadcasts. We have broadcast receiver registered in manifest and handle incoming broadcast for app functionality.

Comment: If possible can you please add the code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a broadcast bug at all, but a knock-on error caused by memory fragmentation (OOM).

Profile your app while it is running and make sure it is not running out of its allocated memory.

Here  are some very [good suggestions](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory) to try. Bouncing the service (kill/relaunch) on a timer might prevent this behavior too.