# android.app.RemoteServiceException "can't deliver broadcast"

Tags: android, exception, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

My app does not uses broadcasts - neither using `Context` nor using `LocalBroadcastManager`. Since I use some external libraries inside the app source code, it might be possible that one of them uses broadcasts inside them.

I can see lots of occurrences of the exception `android.app.RemoteServiceException: can't deliver broadcast` inside Crashlytics and Google Play console, but I don't know what can be causing them.

The complete log can be found below:

```
Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException: can't deliver broadcast
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1644)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

I've already seen some other StackOverflow questions related to this error [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46971153/fatal-exception-android-app-remoteserviceexception-cant-deliver-broadcast-at), but all of them were solved by changes with `sendBroadcast()` logic. Since my app does not sends broadcasts this doesn't help me.

Does someone have any idea about what can be causing the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Me too facing same problem, If you got any solution please share your solution.

Comment: Use `LocalBroadcastManager`   instead of directly registering and sending broadcast see https://stackoverflow.com/a/48866003/6478047