# RemoteServiceException: can't deliver broadcast on All OnePlus devices having oreo and pie

Tags: android, notifications, android-resources, broadcast, remoteserviceexception

I have been seeing this crash in Crashlytics only for OnePlus manufactured devices(one, 3, 5,5T, 6, 6T) having oreo and pie from past 3-4 months. It didn't occur for previous android versions.

```
Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException: can't deliver broadcast
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1844)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6892)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I have looked different posts in stackoverflow, rechecked all the code related to Firebase Messaging and updated to latest version of firebase too but no luck. If anyone faced the same crash, please help. Thanks in advance.

Edit 1: Possible cause may be, I am putting notification icon in mipmap instead of drawable.
https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/app-notification-provokes-continues-system-ui-crashes-and-possible-corruption-of-the-os.713575/

[Android Oreo Notification Crashes System UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47368187/android-oreo-notification-crashes-system-ui)

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69109923

But If I put notification in drawable then how can I fix the resource id so that I won't face the issue mentioned below again(for fixing the resource id I moved notification icon to mipmap from drawable). Recent release of gradle ignores public.xml:

[How to fix: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package *: Couldn't create icon: StatusBarIcon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25317659/how-to-fix-android-app-remoteserviceexception-bad-notification-posted-from-pac)

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40175713/android-getting-cant-deliver-broadcast-error-on-dynamically-registered-broa/47202944#47202944 @shivam gupta

Comment: @Dhanshri, thanks for the response. I have not used localbroadcastmanager anywhere in app. I used explicit intent for sending notification to status bar. It doesn't include action.

Comment: Are you suggesting about click_action value in firebase notification which comes directly from server and delivered to statusbar when app is not in foreground.

Comment: @Pradip, Sending intent is not used in the app, except explicitly for sending notification in status bar.

Comment: @shivamgupta Any workaround for fixing this issue?